# Angular post-data key and value structure

Tags: angular, http-post, postman

I am trying to get data (`an auth token`) from an API using a post with `post-data` as the body. It works in Postman but does not work coming from my code. How should I do this `post-data` key and value structure? I am not sure that `FormData` is the correct thing to use.

[Postman Post with post-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbmDL.png)

Here is my code in Angular 7:

```
getAuthToken(clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken, grantType) {
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('clientId', clientId);
    body.append('clientSecret', clientSecret);
    body.append('refreshToken', refreshToken);
    body.append('grantType', grantType);
    return this.http.post(this.authUrl, body)
    .pipe(
      tap((res) => {
        return res;
      }),
      catchError((err: any) => {
        return throwError('Get Auth Token Error: ' + err);
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you show me error message

Comment: Error getting Access Token: Get Auth Token Error: [object Object]

Comment: can you use console.log(err) in catchError

Comment: I have done that. Here is the result: https://imgur.com/TB3SvF4

Comment: you have cors probleme which backend framework you use

Comment: I think I figured out my problem. I was ignoring the CORS error because in the past I was getting a CORS error as a false alarm (long story). I believe I should move my data request to my Java server. That way, I can ignore the CORS message, since I will not be using a browser to access the data anyway. I think this will make things more secure, and I was planning on doing the next, much larger, data request from the Java server anyway.